# Changing image dynamically in Laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-5

How can I dynamically change an image in:

```
<img id="avatarimg" src="{{ route('avatar.image') }}">
```

...after choosing it in:

```
<input id="userImage" type="file">
```

I thought, for example, like this:

```
 $("#userImage").change(function(){
            alert("!!");
            $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/useravatar1",
            data: {_token:token} })
            .done(function(msg){
                $("#avatarimg").attr("src", msg);
        });
```

And the route:

```
public function getUserAvatar1(){

    $path = Auth::user()->avatar;
    $file = Storage::disk('local')->get($path);
    return new Response($path, 200);

}
```

But it isn't working dynamically, just statically by route.

How can I do this?

Comment: You want to show image on file selection or want to upload it and render the new one?

Comment: It's already uploaded by other route. Now I just want to show it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with Laravel 5.3 but ,

Try to return `$file` instead of `$path` in PHP side and try to `alert(msg)` in response ;

```
$file = Storage::disk('local')->get($path);
return new Response($file, 200);
```

Comment: I tryed that, in alert I recieve just some abracadabra.

Comment: can you post that please

Comment: @ArturHC ok try Storage::url($path); instead of Storage::disk('local')->get($path);

Comment: yes, it return right path in alert, but image isn't  shown. I think it's because of laravel security.

Comment: Are you trying to change the value of `input type="file"` dynamically with Javascript?

Comment: @Michel, no <img> element, attribute is SRC.

Comment: ok I see. Wouldn't it be easier to save the `path` in the DB and return it as response to ajax then use that to change `img` src attribute?

Comment: @Michel, how I understood, no, because of laravel security system.